# Objective-C equivalents of Swift opaque object and boxed type?

Tags: swift, objective-c

Is the Objective-C equivalent of a Swift opaque type just id<protocol>?

What's the equivalent of a boxed type?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted, as text, some example Swift code you are trying to translate. Also show your attempted Objective-C code.

Comment: Objective-C doesn't have associated types in the protocols, so there is no opaque types.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the Objective-C equivalent of a Swift opaque type just id?

No. `id` is equivalent to AnyObject. There is no equivalent to Swift opaque types in ObjC. You could squint really hard and say that both `some ThisProtocol` and `any ThisProtocol` are equivalent to `id <ThisProtocol>`, but they're not. They're fundamentally different (for example, they have different memory layouts in a way that deeply matters), but they have some vague similarities in how they're used.

> What's the equivalent of a boxed type?

I assume you mean an existential type here (such as `any SomeProtocol`). There is no equivalent. In ObjC, everything (except primitives...) is an object. Even classes are objects. Objects can be passed messages. Protocols define a set of methods that can be passed to an object. That's pretty much the entirety of Objective-C. Even things like "lightweight generics" aren't really part of the ObjC language so much as compiler hints that help bridging to Swift. ObjC "properties" are mostly syntactic sugar to create ivars and methods. It's a really simple language. Many things in Swift have no equivalent in ObjC.

But something like `id <ThisProtocol>` would again be the closest kind of equivalency. It's really more like `AnyObject & ThisProtocol` than a "boxed type" in Swift.  That would be a weird thing to write in Swift and possibly isn't even legal, but is what `id <ThisProtocol>` is closest to.

There **is** a "boxed type" in ObjC, but I doubt it's what you mean. It's [NSValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsvalue?language=objc), and it's used to box up primitive types into an object. In technical ways it works exactly like `any` types in Swift. But in how it's used, it's conversely nothing like an `any` type. The languages are just very different.

Comment: I originally typed id<protocol> but the editor only displayed id. Not sure why.

Comment: ah; SO does that because it interprets it as HTML. You have to be careful to put backticks around it to mark it as literal (or use backslash quoting as you did)